# Inline-block inside a flex item causes wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a flex container with two flex items:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

The items float until the available space for the container if less than 100px

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  min-width: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  min-width: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Now, I add some elements to the left item with display:inline-block:

```
<div class="floater"></div>
<div class="floater"></div>
<div class="floater"></div>
<div class="floater"></div>

.floater {
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

But now, the floater elements cause the flex items to wrap.

EDIT: What I try to achieve:

- `.container` width < 100px => `.right` goes under `.left`
- `.container` width >= 100px => `.right` and `.left` are side by side
- The content of `.left` doesn't affect the width of left

So, I want `.left` and `.right` to wrap on small `.containers` (i.e. if the window/browser is small) only.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf9utps1/) with a container of 100px that demonstrates the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually i didn't understood the expected output. You want left and right side by side even if width increase then parent element?

Comment: I want the floater items to wrap before they affect the flex items. For the fiddle, that means that the flex items stay in one line with 40px and 60px and the inner floater items wrap earlier.

Comment: Something like. https://jsfiddle.net/vf9utps1/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a media query.

```
@media ( max-width: 100px ) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

The above rule tells the flex container to switch from `flex-direction: row` (the default setting) to a vertical alignment when the `.container` width is 100px or less.

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vf9utps1/2/) (I used `max-width: 500px` in the demo for illustration purposes).

Depending on your overall objectives, the `flex-wrap: wrap` and `width: 100px` rules on your flex container may not be necessary.

Comment: Argh, thank you! I should have thought of media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from `.container` will make as per your expected.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vf9utps1/1/)**

Comment: But I want them to wrap if the container width is less than 100px. In my project, the container width depends on the width of the browser window.